# How to download an Excel file from the web using Maven?

Tags: java, excel, maven, pom.xml, xlsx

I'm trying to download a *.xlsx* file using the following plugin, in my project's *pom.xml* file:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>getExcelFile</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wget</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://example-url.xlsx</url>
                    <outputFileName>file.xlsx</outputFileName>
                <outputDirectory>${Dir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

However, the file becomes corrupted once downloaded and is empty. It isn't a problem with the file, as whenever I download it from the web and open it manually, it is fine.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: *file becomes corrupted once downloaded and is empty* corrupted or empty?

Comment: can u give phase as `<phase>generate-resources</phase>`

Comment: I did, same thing happens

Comment: First why are you downloading an Excel file for the build? Is it needed for tests ?

Comment: The excel file contains multiple spreadsheets of data, and I've written code to separate this data and process it to be used. The only problem is that I can't get the excel file to properly download into the project without putting it there manually.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Do you need it for tests or in the resulting application? For both cases put it under `src/main/resources` if it's needed in the final application in case for tests only `src/test/resources` and load the file via `getResourceAsStream(..)`...

Comment: In the resulting application